# gsutil rsync 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rsync, gsutil

I am using gsutil command from my Debian server for rsync files to GCP bucket but it fails by following error:

`gsutil -m rsync -r -n files/ gs://my-bucket/files`

```
At source listing 10000...
At source listing 20000...
At source listing 30000...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file://files/: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 51: ordinal not in range(128)
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

gsutil version: 4.52

Around 1TB data need to be transferred.

Comment: Have you tried newer gsutl? 4.52 is 9 months and 9 releases old.

Comment: Yes, now updated to gsutil version: 4.60 still getting the same error.

Comment: Is it completely identical though? I thought they've revisited the error messages to include the file that is causing the issue, can you check? Also are you running one of the supported versions of python (Python 3 (preferred, 3.5 to 3.8) and Python 2 (2.7.9 or higher))?

Comment: Yes exactly same error, this is the Python 2.7.9 version on the server.

Comment: Are there any files in the bucket containing non-asci characters?

Comment: Not sure, as there around 1TB of documents which contain Images, PDF's, Excel, etc.
Even I checked debug mode of gsutil but still it doesn’t list any files.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem by following PHP code which will iterates the source directory and move find non-ascii filenames and move them to different location.

One can also remove non-ascii characters from filename and rename with same logic or can delete using **unlink** method.

```php
<ul>
<?php
// this will help you to debug the code if you get some errors.
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$source = 'source_files/'; // update this with your source path. 
$iterator = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));

$dest = 'destination_path'; // update it with your destination path

foreach($iterator as $filename => $path) {
    if(preg_match('/[^\x20-\x7e]/', $path)) {
        echo "<li>".$filename."</li>";
        // rename($filename, $dest.pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME)); // Uncomment if you want to move it with some other location. 

        // unlink($filename); // Uncomment if you want to delete that file.
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

***NOTE: Make sure you have set correct permissions to source and destination directory.***

Hope it will help someone in the future.

Thanks